# расположение элементов в Slick slider

Tags: html, css, slick.js

Как сделать,чтобы последняя картинка прижалась к краю слайдера, как первая ? Потому что расстояние между кнопками переключения слайдов разная получается. Хотел использовать `display:flex` и `justify-content: space-between` , но что-то не удалось применить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
$('.multiple-items').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 4,
  dots:true
});
```

```css
body{
  background-color: #555;
}

.multiple-items{
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.css"> 


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  
</head>

<body>
  
    <div class="multiple-items">
      <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/263/250?random=1" alt=""></div>
      <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/263/250?random=2" alt=""></div>
      <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/263/250?random=3" alt=""></div>
      <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/263/250?random=4" alt=""></div>
      <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/263/250?random=5" alt=""></div>
      <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/263/250?random=6" alt=""></div>
      <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/263/250?random=7" alt=""></div>
      <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/263/250?random=8" alt=""></div>
      
      
    </div>
  

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-migrate/3.1.0/jquery-migrate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Просто задай изображению 100% ширину внутри блока,
а если тебе нужны отступы между изображениями сделай их сам но уже контролируй их сам

Comment: @SergeiDimitriev так а если по макету ширина у фото не 100%, а должна быть такая, как она есть , то как быть ?

Comment: @PeterSmith Сделай обертку у изображения
контролируй оберткой ширину
или если уж ты хочешь оставлять размер по живому фото(что не стоит делать потому что если фото будет больше оно просто вылезет за приделы блока).
можешь сделать так `img {margin: 0 auto;}`